# Exposing a QStringList as a QtScript array

Tags: qt, qtscript

I have some QtScripts that need to operate on some C++ data. I already expose a number of variables via `QScriptEngine::globalObject().setProperty()`, but this only seems to work out of the box for simple data types and QStrings.

I've tried using `QScriptEngine::newVariant()`, but none of `QVariant`'s member functions are exposed to the script engine.

Ideally I'd like to be able to convert the QStringList into a plain QtScript array and call native array functions on it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I've not actually started using Qt Script yet, but I do recall seeing [qScriptValueFromSequence](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#qScriptValueFromSequence) when trawling the docs - is it of any use here?

Comment: Worked like a charm, if you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you're after [`qScriptValueFromSequence`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#qScriptValueFromSequence).